# Docusign integration with Sharepoint Framework without signatures being uploaded on docusign's server

Tags: reactjs, docusignapi, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

We want to integrate docusign with one of our applications built in Sharepoint Framework (React).

Requirement is not to upload any e-signatures on external servers.

Question 1: How and where to prompt users for first time recording of their signatures?

Question 2: Can this be achieved inside the application without having the user go to their email and sign by redirecting them to docusign's server?

Any documentation on above questions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question Aquib. Both these things can be done using the DocuSign eSignature REST API. I would recommend you look at some of code examples that show how to do these things here:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples
Specifically, let me answer your questions:
1. Users can select their signatures the first time they are asked to sign, whether this is done via an integration or via direct send from DocuSign application. The system will remember your selection. If you have an account you can also go directly to your account and change this under "preferences".
2. You would want to use "embedded signing" which is what we call the ability to embed signing experience in your integration. You can see code examples for this here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing

Comment: Thanks for the answer those are really helpful, I have managed to get the sample code running for embedded signing ceremony. Is it possible to open the signing ceremony page in a dialog (I understand iframe is not a good option) so user does not feel they are leaving the application?
Also, are there any documentations for achieving the same in react application ?

Comment: yes, you can use embedded signing and have it in an iframe

Comment: archiving in react application - not sure what that means. Can you explain?

Comment: not archiving, I meant doing the same thing in a react application as currently there is no documentation for that.

Comment: did you also send us an email? I think Larry replied so you are good now?